# qabstractlistmodel with a QList datatype to return to a delegate(as a model) which has a list in it

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a Qabstractlistmodel in my project and I have a data which is a Qlist of a class called host
Now ,I have a primary list model which has delegate say *delegate1* 
Now, I want to have the qlist as a model for the secondary list element in my delegate 1

Can anyone say how to do this?
**If possible can this model be editable**
I came across QVariantList But can i edit this from qml??


Detailed view of data set
class Vm derived from Qabstractlistmodel(for editable model in qml)
->members
->QString name
->Qlist class host(this is to be displayed in qml's delegate list)
--->member of host class
--->int id
--->QString value


Now i want the member of data type class host (a model) to be a passed as a QAbstractlistmodel 's data

Comment: Could you explain better?

Comment: yeah i have edited the question